# XAML Path sizing and positioning

Tags: silverlight, xaml, path, grid, stackpanel

I am trying to design a template for a TabItem using paths and rectangles.  The sides of the tab layout are paths to accommodate curves in the design.  I am having a problem with getting the sides to line up/resize correctly.  Here's my XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
 <Path Stretch="UniformToFill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 97.1985,101.669L 104.824,95.0005C 105.574,94.3338 106.921,93.8627 107.824,93.9171L 107.824,101.667L 97.1985,101.669 Z "/>
 <Grid>
          <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="#FF000000"/>
  <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" x:Name="HeaderTopSelected" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" IsTabStop="False" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"/>
 </Grid>
 <Path Stretch="UniformToFill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 118.714,101.678L 111.088,95.0097C 110.338,94.343 108.991,93.8719 108.088,93.9264L 108.088,101.676L 118.714,101.678 Z "/>
</StackPanel>
```

(I apologize for the lack of line breaks.  I'm new to StackOverflow and don't know how to insert them, nor do I have the time to figure it out :D)

The code snippet posted *almost* works:  The side paths are the correct size, but they do not display in a line, they overlap behind the rectangle/next element.  If I set a fixed width they work as well, but I can't set the width as fixed, they need to be fluid in case the content of the tab exceeds the basic height.

[**This is an idea of what I would like to get**](http://gallery.me.com/georgeloring/100172/Ryan)

The sides (paths) grow uniformally based on the height of the ContentControl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Take 3 (now we know what the requirement is):

Basically to get the desired effect you need your 2 side parts to resize their width if their height changes, in order to keep a fixed aspect ratio. This will force the parent container to expand as the actual content gets taller and the sides get taller to match. none of the containers (including ViewBox) work exactly this way.

You could use a custom container to do this, but the preferred solution would be to create a behaviour that retains its object's aspect ratio on height changes. We will call it a FixedAspectBehavior:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public class FixedAspectRatioBehavior : TargetedTriggerAction<FrameworkElement>
    {
        public double AspectRatio { get; set; }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            FrameworkElement element = this.AssociatedObject as FrameworkElement;
            if (element != null)
            {
                AspectRatio = element.Width/element.Height;
                element.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(element_SizeChanged);
            }
        }

        void element_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement element = AssociatedObject as FrameworkElement;
            element.Width = element.Height * AspectRatio;
        }

        protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The layout requires some work as self resizing elements (of type path) do some very weird things depending on their parent container. I had to use ViewBoxes as the parent of the paths, combined with the behaviours to get the desired result:

[image]

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Viewbox>
            <Path Stretch="UniformToFill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 97.1985,101.669L 104.824,95.0005C 105.574,94.3338 106.921,93.8627 107.824,93.9171L 107.824,101.667L 97.1985,101.669 Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <local:FixedAspectRatioBehavior/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Path>
        </Viewbox>
    <Grid Width="Auto" Background="#FFFF0D0D" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="#FFD21F1F"/>
        <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" x:Name="HeaderTopSelected" FontSize="{TemplateBinding Control.FontSize}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Control.Foreground}" IsTabStop="False" Cursor="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.Cursor}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment}"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16"><Run Text="This is just a very string to see "/><LineBreak/><Run Text="what happens  when we get to a size where the container should get larger than the default size"/></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
    <Viewbox Grid.Column="2">
        <Path Stretch="UniformToFill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 118.714,101.678L 111.088,95.0097C 110.338,94.343 108.991,93.8719 108.088,93.9264L 108.088,101.676L 118.714,101.678 Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <local:FixedAspectRatioBehavior/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Path>
    </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
```

### Take 1 (*obsolete now, as is 2 below*):

The width of a path does not push along items in a stack panel. In that respect it's width is useless except to scale the item.

To get the effect you wanted, group each path into a grid. The size problem then goes away.

[image]

Apologies for turning your rectangle horrible red to show it clearly :)

[image]

XAML below:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto">
    <Grid>
        <Path Stretch="UniformToFill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 97.1985,101.669L 104.824,95.0005C 105.574,94.3338 106.921,93.8627 107.824,93.9171L 107.824,101.667L 97.1985,101.669 Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutOverrides="Width"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Width="100" Background="#FFFF0D0D">
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="#FFD21F1F"/>
        <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" x:Name="HeaderTopSelected" FontSize="{TemplateBinding Control.FontSize}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Control.Foreground}" IsTabStop="False" Cursor="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.Cursor}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment}"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Path Stretch="UniformToFill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 118.714,101.678L 111.088,95.0097C 110.338,94.343 108.991,93.8719 108.088,93.9264L 108.088,101.676L 118.714,101.678 Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutOverrides="Width"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

### Take 2 (*also obsolete now, see take 3 at the top*):

If you require fixed end widths, use a grid instead of a stack panel (XAML below).

[image]

If you require something else, please provide a couple of screen shots of the desired effect.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Path Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 97.1985,101.669L 104.824,95.0005C 105.574,94.3338 106.921,93.8627 107.824,93.9171L 107.824,101.667L 97.1985,101.669 Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutOverrides="Width"/>
    <Grid Width="Auto" Background="#FFFF0D0D" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="#FFD21F1F"/>
        <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" x:Name="HeaderTopSelected" FontSize="{TemplateBinding Control.FontSize}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Control.Foreground}" IsTabStop="False" Cursor="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.Cursor}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment}" Content="Hello there.... this is a long string to see what happens"/>
    </Grid>
    <Path Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 118.714,101.678L 111.088,95.0097C 110.338,94.343 108.991,93.8719 108.088,93.9264L 108.088,101.676L 118.714,101.678 Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: I tried wrapping a Grid around the two paths, but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: If you have tried the set-up shown above, can you please provide a screen shot of the problem? I am guessing you actually want to use a 3 column grid instead of a stack panel, but need to know more about your specific problem.

Comment: Okay, using the code snippet you posted above I was able to get it working in a way, but the problem is the paths seem to be causing the grids to stretch vertically to take up the available parent node size unless I explicitly set the height.  Ideally, if possible, I would like for the ContentControl to dictate the overall height of the entire stackpanel and have the two paths on the side grow uniformally as needed.  I tried doing this with a grid in place of the stackpanel, but it had the same issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: The second version above should resize to fit the content and stretch the side shapes vertically only to match. Let me know if you still have problems. If that is still not right it is down to my not understanding your requirements (a napkin sketch would do:))

Comment: I appreciate your help so far, by the way.  We're getting there!  Unfortunately I cannot post an image because I'm too new to StackOverflow.  I'll try to find somewhere to upload it and post a link.

Comment: Aha... light blinks on... Your requirement means that you want the side parts to actually force a change of width based on a height change (basically keep the aspect ratio constant). You need a custom behaviour, as none of the built-in container types support that feature. If you can wait a while I will see if I can whip up a FixedAspectRatioBehavior for you after work.

Comment: You are awesome.  I'm anxious to see how a custom behavior is written/implemented.

Comment: All done... Behaviours are really cool. Just need to think of reusable behaviour like this one to implement. Let me know if there are any problems. I did not test any of this inside a templated user control. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond.  This works great.  Thanks again for your help :)